# Is there any possibility to add sensitive field in the nifi processor?

Tags: curl, apache-nifi, rest

I am using ExecuteStreamCommand Processor in Nifi 1.9.1 and instead of exposing password in  curl command, I would like to hide it.

I want to generate token using curl command through ExecuteStreamCommand Processor or suggest a better solution where i can generate a token using Ldap enabled Nifi API

```
ExecuteStreamCommand Property:

Command Argument: -sSK;-u;<userid>:<password>;-d;username=<userid>&password=<password>;--request;POST;--header;Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;--header;Accept:text/plain;--data;${data:toString()};https://<nifiurl>/nifi-api/access/token

Command Path : curl
```

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Sensitive properties have to be manually specified in the source code for the processor. As a work around, [sensitive parameters](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#parameter-contexts) should work just fine if you upgrade to a recent version of NiFi. You should do that anyway because 1.9.1 is not the most recent 1.9.X release and contains some known bugs worth an upgrade to at least 1.9.2 (parameters didn't get added until 1.10, so I would recommend going to 1.12.1 our latest)

Comment: Thank you Mike for your response. I will upgrade then.